# How do I setup a ROWVERSION/TIMESTAMP datatype column using FluentMigrator?

Tags: .net, sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, fluent-migrator

I am trying to use the `ROWVERSION` (or `TIMESTAMP`) datatype on a SQL Server table for optimistic concurrency control.

My table is setup using FluentMigrator and I do not know how to get the datatype I need.  According to [Microsoft's article on `ROWVERSION`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx), a **nonnullable `ROWVERSION`** column is semantically equivalent to a **binary(8)** column; the **nullable `ROWVERSION`** datatype is equivalent to a **varbinary(8)**.

Here is an example and as close as I can get...

```
public override void Up()
    {
        Create.Table("Test")
            .WithColumn("Id").AsInt32().Identity().PrimaryKey()
            .WithColumn("Description").AsAnsiString(255)
            .WithColumn("RowVersion").AsBinary(8).NotNullable(); 
    }
```

**`.WithColumn("RowVersion").AsBinary(8).NotNullable();`** is the line I can't figure out...  There is no **`.AsRowversion`** or **`.AsTimestamp`** option.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know FluentMigrator, sorry. But FluentNHibernate has a method Version(x => x.VersionProperty) in ClassMap<T>, that enables NHibernate optimistic locking (the property can be any of any integer type or DateTime). Is there nothing similar in FluentMigrator?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Wow!  How something can be so simple that I look right over the obvious...

```
.WithColumn("Version").AsCustom("rowversion").NotNullable();
```